# Why does python35 import try to load python27 package?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have `python2.7` and `python3.5` installed via Macports. I am trying to get neovim up and running and for this I ran

```
$ sudo pip2 install neovim
$ sudo pip-3.5 install neovim
```

Which installs the packages into different subdirs of `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/`. Now when running Python 3.5, `import neovim` tries to load the 2.7 package (which fails), as I can see from the stack trace.

The full error is this:

```
$ python3.5 -c "import neovim"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neovim/msgpack_rpc/event_loop/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .uv import UvEventLoop
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neovim/msgpack_rpc/event_loop/uv.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pyuv
ImportError: No module named 'pyuv'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neovim/msgpack_rpc/event_loop/asyncio.py", line 19, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/asyncio/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 18, in <module>
    import concurrent.futures
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 357
    raise type(self._exception), self._exception, self._traceback
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neovim/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .msgpack_rpc import (ErrorResponse, child_session, socket_session,
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neovim/msgpack_rpc/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .event_loop import EventLoop
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neovim/msgpack_rpc/event_loop/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .asyncio import AsyncioEventLoop
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neovim/msgpack_rpc/event_loop/asyncio.py", line 22, in <module>
    import trollius as asyncio
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trollius/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .base_events import *
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trollius/base_events.py", line 39, in <module>
    from . import coroutines
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trollius/coroutines.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import futures
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trollius/futures.py", line 19, in <module>
    from . import executor
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trollius/executor.py", line 12, in <module>
    import concurrent.futures
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 357
    raise type(self._exception), self._exception, self._traceback
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What do I have to do in order for Python 2.7 and 3 to coexist peacefully on my system?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? This sounds like strange behaviour: I have multiple versions of Python (some of them from Macports) coexisting peacefully on my OS X machine.

Comment: @MarkDickinson See updated question.

Comment: You probably have the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable set in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile

Comment: @mata Yes I have, since Python 2.7 won't find packages installed with pip if I don't. At least not all of them. Removing the env var lets me `import neovim` in python 3, but other packages won't import in python 2. I realise one should use virtualenv for this, but I assume there must be a way to have python 2 automatically search in the directory where pip installs all packages. Are there independent env vars for py2* and py3*?

Comment: Huh, I uninstalled and reinstalled the offending module and now it's working again. Maybe I used the wrong pip the first time around. The `PYTHONPATH` was really the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem as well, but it was *not* related to `PYTHONPATH`, which on my machine was unset. In my situation Python and `pip` were installed via MacPorts. Cleaning, self-updating MacPorts and then updating `pip` to the most recent version, and then running the following resolved the issue:

```
port select --set pip pip35
```